Not possible to connect to remote Oracle XE with public IP
I have a problem with my database, I cannot access to it via public IP (remote).
I have developed a java stocks program, which uses JDBC to connect to DB.
My database is Oracle Database Express Edition (XE), mounted in Windows 10 to serve a stocks control program. The program works perfect while running on the same PC (localhost), but recently I wanted to access to it via remote connection.
The steps I followed are these:
1. Tell my ISP company to fix me an static public IP.
2. Configure a forwarding port in my router.
3. Create an SSH tunnel on server to route the traffic from forwarded port to database port (1521).

Comprobations I have done:
-Reaching the opened port via external access: OK
-Testing the SSH tunnel on server to be working. IP and port put on a browser, and the command line where the tunnel is debugging shows connection attempts. OK
-Testing SQLplus to connect to the remote server with public IP. ERROR (BUT DEBUG CONSOLE ON SSH TUNNEL SHOWS A CONNECTION ATTEMPT). ORA-12537: TNS: closed connection.
-Testing JDBC to connect from my application to the remote server with public IP. ERROR. Network adapter cannot establish the connection. (NO CONNECTION ATTEMPT).
I also have configured a DDNS in the router with noIP, but the behavior is the same.
Anyone has an idea about this? I have tried several times.
UPDATE:
After downloading Orace Call Interface, SQLplus connects, but my Java application does not show any sign of connection.
Error:
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Error de E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
Error en la conexión de la base de datos

Sounds like your database server may have a local firewall, or the Oracle Listener is only listening on localhost.

@pmdba yes, i have though that, but the redirection is done pointing to that device, to its local IP, so, in localhost, it should listen, right?

Your ssh tunnel port redirection must point specifically to the localhost ip address (127.0.0.1) as the target.

@pmdba yes, it is pointing to "localhost", and trying with sqlplus it shows a connection attempt on the debug screen (but shows in sqlplus a credential fail). But trying with my java application, which uses JDBC, the debug of the ssh tunnel does not show anything

ORA-12537: TNS: closed connection. this message is almost always from a firewall rejection. It is not a credential failure.

@pmdba that is not my error, my error is "cannot retrieve credentials" I do not remember the ORA id.

That is the error in your post. If you're getting something different, please include accurate details in your question or we can't really help you.

@pmdba sorry, it is right, that was my initial problem, but I don't know why, the ORA-**** has changed.

@pmdba after downloading OCI, SQLplus can connect, but my application does not.
